# Iterating through members list to identify all accounts that were created at the same time (Python, discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

+I'm trying to make a Discord bot that fetches an ID of one of spammers, grabs its creation date and then compares results against list of all server members to make a list of spammer bots' IDs to *massban them (as they often being created at the same time).

The problem is it don't find anyone and printing 'No additional users were found with such register date.' (see 30th row) in a console a ton of times. Perhaps I'm missing break but wouldn't it destroy search loop before all IDs would be found?

<strike>Ideally the script would allow some time tolerance (like in 23rd row - not just plus, but also minus. The closest thing I foind is uncertainties Python package, but it would require converting the datetime object into string to operate and vice-versa. Perhaps there's more convinivent way?)</strike>

Python ver 3.8.5

discord ver 1.0.1

discord.py ver 1.5.1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot is online')

@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Moderators", "Staff")
async def listids(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
  if member == None:
    await ctx.send('No ID was provided. Please provide an ID.') #asking user to provide an ID
  try:
    timedeltaA = timedelta(0, 6000) #testing purposes. change to 60
    timedeltaB = timedelta(0, 6000) #testing purposes. change to 60
    creationtimeA = member.created_at + timedeltaA
    creationtimeB = member.created_at - timedeltaB
    print('Searching for accounts created between ' + str(creationtimeB) + ' and ' + str(creationtimeA))
    #print(ctx.guild.members)
    for x in ctx.guild.members: #parsing all members of the given server and comparing their creation dates against the aforementioned criteria
        if x.created_at > creationtimeA and x.created_at < creationtimeB: #MAKE AND CHECK AND COMPARE AGAINST TWO CONDITIONS
            accounts = ', '.join(x.id) #converting results to a string
            await ctx.send('The following accounts were created at the same time: ' + accounts)
            break
        else:
            await ctx.send('No additional users were found with such register date.')
            print('No additional users were found with such register date.')
            return
  except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      return

client.run('token')
```

Thank you for your time, wish you a nice and pleasant day! ;3

Comment: You're not checking against the same day, you're checking against the same time, down to the millisecond, wont work that way

Comment: @Ceres thank you for your reply. I've slightly edited the code. What I found is that ctx.guild.members array doesn't contain created_at attribute so I should somehow loop through the entire list to get the member object and then get the created_at attribute. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using timedelta and messing around with time, use the builtin datetime support.

```
creation_day = member.created_at.date
for x in ctx.guild.members:
    if x.created_ad.date == creation_day:
        print(x, member, 'are created in same day')
```

This would show all the accounts created in the same day, if you want hours or minutes, you might have to convert the datetime into a preferable formated string and check against that. I wouldn't recommend using timedelta and seconds.